# Type of chip to enable 230VAC when circuit closed?

Tags: power, ac, switches

I am looking for an IC that could potentially resolve an issue I have on a project.

I am using two reed switches to close the circuit when two magnetic contacts are close enough. This will close the circuit and enable 230VAC to function. I cannot remember the name of that kind of chip, but something to do with 0 level crossing, if that helps?

Comment: 1) Why an IC? I think a relay (mechanical or solid state) might do the job as well. 2) What are you switching on the 230 V AC side? 3) Why "zero crossing"? Explain why you think you need that.

Comment: @Mateusz I think your thinking of a triac

Answer (score 1):

An electromagnetic relay should be good enough, with no need for any 'zero crossing'.

[image]

Comment: Thanks allot I will try this design. This makes allot of sense! :)

Comment: Parameters for relay selection: 1. Coil current rating < reed switch current rating  2. Contact current rating > load current.

Answer (score 0):

A solid-state relay would do the job. Perhaps this is the type of silicon IC you are trying to remember. If not, then an SCR may be what you were thinking with dimmer circuits. Also, an old fashion relay would work too. The main points you need to be aware of is the current demand for your 230 VAC and to spec out the relay to meet this requirement. Another point is the controlling voltage needed for the relay. This should be done with the reed switches, but also keep in mind that they can be current limited too so check those specs.